# Add parameter within SQL Query - Python

Tags: python, sql

I have defined a parameter called CODE.

CODE is a list of strings, for instance 'Car', 'Bike', 'Boat' and so on.

I need to execute SQL Querys that have the following pattern:

```
Select * from Table when CODE=Car
```

Or

```
Select * from Table when CODE=Bike
```

and so on.

Is it posible to use the parameter directly in the Query?

Like somenthing thike the following:

```
Select * from Table when CODE = Parameter CODE?
```

Edit:

Im using Python to make the Query. Variable CODE comes from a colomn of a DataFrame as it follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc                                              

CODE=Table1['CODE']

dbconnection=pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'  
'Server=XXXX,1234;'                           
'Database=AAAA;'
'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

sql="SELECT * FROM DATABASE  WHERE CODE = 'Bike'"

Selection=pd.read_sql(sql,dbconnection)
```

Comment: are you using Python to make the query or is this all in SQL?

Comment: Im using Python. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python [string formatting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-formatting-in-python/) to replace the value. One type of formatting is the f-string syntax

```
#OLD (your approach)
sql="SELECT * FROM DATABASE  WHERE CODE = 'Bike'"

#NEW - with formatting
sql=f"SELECT * FROM DATABASE  WHERE CODE = '{CODE}'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't a long list of values in CODE, then you can do the following:

```
select * from Table where CODE IN ('Car', 'Bike', 'Boat', 'Motor', ...);
```